# dotnet build failing because project not found

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I have a YAML file with tasks to copy & publish files to artifact and download the artifact:

Log for task DownloadPipelineArtifact@2:

```
Downloading: D:\a\1\s\Service\ProjectName\Repositories.Logging/Repositories.Logging.csproj
```

Then, I have a task to build. The build fails on this task.

Log for task DotNetCoreCLI@2:

```
Skipping project "D:\a\1\s\Service\ProjectName\Repositories.Logging\Repositories.Logging.csproj" because it was not found.
```

Why does it say skipping project because it was not found even though log for DownloadPipelineArtifact@2 shows the same path? What am I missing and how do I fix that?

UPDATE:

I know that there is a difference in the slashes. However, I don't have conrol over updating the slashes:

Tasks to copy, publish, download:

```
    - task: CopyFiles@2
      displayName: 'copy service'
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: 'Service\ProjectName'
        contents: '**'
        TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: 'publish artifact'
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'        
        ArtifactName: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'

    - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
      inputs:
        artifactName: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
        downloadPath: Service\ProjectName
```

On updating download task to:

```
    - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
      inputs:
        artifactName: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
        downloadPath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\Service\ProjectName
```

I see the following log from DownloadBuildArtifacts@0:

```
Downloaded to D:\a\1\s\Service\ProjectName\20201118.10\Repositories.Logging\Repositories.Logging.csproj
```

and following log from DotNetCoreCLI@2:

```
D:\a\1\s\Service\ProjectName\Repositories.Logging\Repositories.Logging.csproj because it was not found
```

In this case I see the slashes correctly. Is it possible to remove:

```
20201118.10
```

from downloadPath so that it becomes:

```
D:\a\1\s\Service\ProjectName\Repositories.Logging\Repositories.Logging.csproj
```

Comment: Please notice that you have different slashes `Repositories.Logging/Repositories.Logging.csproj` and here `Repositories.Logging\Repositories.Logging.csproj`. Please make sure you ahve the same and try again.

Comment: Please see m updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to remove `20201118.10` from `downloadPath`.

We could not remove the artifact Name `20201118.10` when we use the task `Download build artifacts`.

When we check the task `Download build artifacts` in the classic mode, we could to know the option `Artifact name` is **required**:

[image]

To resolve this issue, we could add a copy task to copy files to `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\Service\ProjectName` folder

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Move artifact Name'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\Service\ProjectName\$(Build.BuildNumber)'
    TargetFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\Service\ProjectName'
```

Or you could specify the path including the  artifact Name `20201118.10` when you build the project:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build'
  inputs:
    projects: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\Service\ProjectName\$(Build.BuildNumber)\Repositories.Logging\Repositories.Logging.csproj'
```